# vscode not showing the changes made in a file

Tags: visual-studio-code

In a folder in my project I have a few files. Git and vscode works without any problems in every file, except one. In `test.py` vscode doesn't show the modified lines like this [image]. It says modified [image: on th], but it doesn't show the changes made. What should I do to make vscode show the changes made to the code in `test.py`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why aren't SCM diff decorations showing in the gutter in VS Code 1.76.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75715788/why-arent-scm-diff-decorations-showing-in-the-gutter-in-vs-code-1-76-1)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like errors in extensions can **break the git changes interface in gutters**.

Try **turning off all extensions** and restarting Code.

Add back extensions one-by-one until you find the one causing the issue.